# Does the position at which maximum distance occurs in a KS test make a difference?

Tags: regression, logistic, kolmogorov-smirnov-test, validation, cumulative-distribution-function

From my understanding of the KS test, fromt the CDF of two datasets, it measures the distance between the two distributions at various points and and compares the 'maximum distance' to a predefined value that depends on the sample size (or degrees of freedom) to test our null hypothesis which is that the two distributions are similar.

My doubt is, does it make a difference as to where this 'point of maximum difference' occurs in the CDF? If it is at a point higher in the CDF or lower?

Edit - I forgot to provide more context to my question. I am looking at this from a model validation (logisitic regression) POV. When we get a KS stat comparing the CDFs of our actual outputs and predicted outputs, does it matter at what point the max distance is found?

Comment: Not to the K-S statistic, no.

Comment: In terms of interpretation?

Comment: Interpretation of what? The KS statistic in the test? No - you test what you test. If you want the test to behave differently, you choose a test that does that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To clarify the question: you compute
$$
F_n(x)={1 \over n}\sum_{i=1}^n I_{X_i\leq x}
$$
from your data $X_1, \ldots, X_n$.

The textbook Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic is
$$
D_n= \sup_x |F_n(x)-F(x)|,
$$
where $F$ is the CDF of the null distribution.

So **no**, the $x$ value for which the $\sup$ is attained (if at all) doesn't matter for the textbook KS test.

However, as a statistician you try to exploit your data in full.  I haven't done calculations but perhaps variations of the KS statistic where you examine distances for $x$ in a neighbourhood where e.g. $F'(x)$ is large gives a better test in certain scenarios.  I don't think it would be worth investigating though.  The $p$-values would likely need to be tabulated via simulation etc.

Comment: However, a homelier comment is that it's hard for K-S to find differences in the tails **in situations where you want to use it**: as both CDFs start at 0 and end at 1 the difference between them will tend to 0 as you approach the more extreme limits. If there is major offlap of distributions then one cumulative probability could be 0 and the other large, but in practice if distributions are that different you don't reach for this test. No one tests whether mice and elephants have different weight distributions, for example, or whether human heights fit a Gaussian with mean 4 metres.

Comment: That's a word I haven't seen before - *offlap*. One test that takes account of the tendency of distributions to be closer together when the cdf is near 0 and 1 is the Anderson-Darling test.